# Record can not be deleted

Tags: android, sqlite

record can not be deleted from database 
here is my delete record query code.

```
 public void deleteRecordShop(String shopid) {
        String status = "1";
        SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();
        try {
            db.delete(TABLE_MASTER,
                    KEY_ID_ONILINE + "=? AND " + KEY_SYNC_STATUS + "=?", new String[]{shopid, status});

        } catch (SQLException e) {
            e.getMessage();
        }
        db.close();

    }
```

Comment: There doesn't appear to be anything wrong with the above code. Therefore the issue would appear to be due to the row (record) not existing according to the where criteria or with how you are coming to the conclusion that the row hasn't been deleted. It's impossible to say without code showing how the above code is invoked and how the non-deletion is determined. You could always check the value returned from `delete` to determine which of the two.

Comment: The above code is wrong if the values in the table are not actually strings. (How do you write them?)